# Subsample 1-D array using 2-D indices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

**Background:**
The data I'm using is being extracted from a `netCDF4` object, which creates a numpy masked array at initialization, but does not appear to support the numpy `reshape()` method, making it only possible to reshape after all the data has been copied = way too slow.

**Question:** How can I sub-sample a 1-D array, that is basically a flattened 2-D array, without reshaping it?

```
import numpy

a1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
               [11,22,33,44],
               [111,222,333,444],
               [1111,2222,3333,4444],
               [11111,22222,33333,44444]])

a2 = np.ravel(a1)

rows, cols = a1.shape

row1 = 1
row2 = 3

col1 = 1
col2 = 3
```

I would like to use a fast slicing method that doesn't require reshaping the 1-D array to a 2-D array.

**Desired Output:**

```
np.ravel(a1[row1:row2, col1:col2])

>> array([ 22,  33, 222, 333])
```

I got as far as getting the start and ending positions, but this just selects ALL data between these points (i.e. extra columns).

```
idx_start = (row1 * cols) + col1
idx_end   = (row2 * cols) + col2
```

**Update:**
I just tried [Jaime's brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16240395/943773), but it appears that `netCDF4` won't allow for 2-D indices.

```
z = dataset.variables["z"][idx]
  File "netCDF4.pyx", line 2613, in netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__ (netCDF4.c:29583)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netCDF4_utils.py", line 141, in _StartCountStride
    raise IndexError("Index cannot be multidimensional.")
IndexError: Index cannot be multidimensional.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this, and though it doesn't copy ALL of the data, it is still copying data that I don't want into memory. This can probably be improved and I hope there is a better solution out there.

```
zi = 0 
# Create zero array with the appropriate length for the data subset
z = np.zeros((col2 - col1) * (row2 - row1))
# Process number of rows for which data is being extracted
for i in range(row2 - row1):
    # Pull row, then desired elements of that row into buffer
    tmp = ((dataset.variables["z"][(i*cols):((i*cols)+cols)])[col1:col2])
    # Add each item in buffer sequentially to data array
    for j in tmp:
        z[zi] = j 
        # Keep a count of what index position the next data point goes to
        zi += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want with a combination of [`np.ogrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) and [`np.ravel_multi_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html):

```
>>> a1
array([    1,     2,     3,     4,    11,    22,    33,    44,   111,
         222,   333,   444,  1111,  2222,  3333,  4444, 11111, 22222,
       33333, 44444])
>>> idx = np.ravel_multi_index((np.ogrid[1:3,1:3]), (5, 4))
>>> a1[idx]
array([[ 22,  33],
       [222, 333]])
```

You could of course ravel this array to get a 1D return if that's what you are after. Notice also that this is a copy of your original data, not a view.

---

**EDIT** You can keep the same general approach, replacing `np.ogrid` with `np.mgrid` and reshaping it to get a flat return:

```
>>> idx = np.ravel_multi_index((np.mgrid[1:3,1:3].reshape(2, -1)), (5, 4))
>>> a1[idx]
array([ 22,  33, 222, 333])
```

Comment: 1-D return doesn't matter as much as taking the slice from its original 1-D dimension. Checking this out now. Looks perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Should the `np.ravel_multi_index` `dims` of `(4,4)` not be `(5,4)` here?

Comment: @shootingstars Yes, my bad, I counted wrong, have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. After trying this (awesome solution), It appears `netCDF4` doesn't like 2-D indices. Any suggestions? I've added the error to my question.

Comment: Just tried that and got a `Killed`. It may be something I did, but I'll have to recheck in the morning. Thanks for the help Jaime!

Comment: It looks like this method is too resource intensive given the size of the dataset that I am extracting. I've verified I'm doing things correctly, and it is still giving me a `killed` process.

Answer (score 0):

Here a lean proposition

```
a1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
               [11,22,33,44],
               [111,222,333,444],
               [1111,2222,3333,4444],
               [11111,22222,33333,44444]])

row1 = 1; row2 = 3; ix = slice(row1,row2)
col1 = 1; col2 = 3; iy = slice(col1,col2)
n = (row2-row1)*(col2-col1)

print(a1[ix,iy]);    print()
print(a1[ix,iy].reshape(1,n))
.
[[ 22  33]
 [222 333]]

[[ 22  33 222 333]]
```

reshape in Python is not expensive, and [slice is fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290102/is-2-dimensional-numpy-take-fast).