# Is 2-dimensional numpy.take fast?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, take

numpy.take can be applied in **2 dimensions** with

```
np.take(np.take(T,ix,axis=0), iy,axis=1 )
```

I tested the stencil of the discret 2-dimensional Laplacian

```
ΔT = T[ix-1,iy] + T[ix+1, iy] + T[ix,iy-1] + T[ix,iy+1] - 4 * T[ix,iy]
```

with 2 take-schemes and the usual numpy.array scheme. The functions p and q are introduced for a leaner code writing and adress the axis 0 and 1 in different order. This is the code:

```
nx = 300; ny= 300
T  = np.arange(nx*ny).reshape(nx, ny)
ix = np.linspace(1,nx-2,nx-2,dtype=int) 
iy = np.linspace(1,ny-2,ny-2,dtype=int)
#------------------------------------------------------------
def p(Φ,kx,ky):
    return np.take(np.take(Φ,ky,axis=1), kx,axis=0 )
#------------------------------------------------------------
def q(Φ,kx,ky):
    return np.take(np.take(Φ,kx,axis=0), ky,axis=1 )
#------------------------------------------------------------
%timeit ΔT_n = T[0:nx-2,1:ny-1] + T[2:nx,1:ny-1] + T[1:nx-1,0:ny-2]  + T[1:nx-1,2:ny] - 4.0 * T[1:nx-1,1:ny-1] 
%timeit ΔT_t = p(T,ix-1,iy)  + p(T,ix+1,iy)  + p(T,ix,iy-1)  + p(T,ix,iy+1)  - 4.0 * p(T,ix,iy)
%timeit ΔT_t = q(T,ix-1,iy)  + q(T,ix+1,iy)  + q(T,ix,iy-1)  + q(T,ix,iy+1)  - 4.0 * q(T,ix,iy)
.
1000 loops, best of 3: 944 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.11 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.02 ms per loop
```

The results seem to be obvious:

1. usual numpy index arithmeitk is fastest
2. take-scheme q takes 100% longer (= C-ordering ?)
3. take-scheme p takes 200% longer (= Fortran-ordering ?)

Not even the **1-dimensional**
[example of the scipy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) indicates that numpy.take is fast:

```
a = np.array([4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8])
indices = [0, 1, 4]
%timeit np.take(a, indices)
%timeit a[indices]
.
The slowest run took 6.58 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.32 µs per loop
The slowest run took 7.34 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.87 µs per loop
```

Does anybody has experiences how to make numpy.take fast ? It would be an flexible and attractive way for lean code writing that is fast in coding and
[is told to be fast in execution](http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-01/) as well. Thank your for some hints to improve my approach !

Comment: How about with `np.ix_` : `T[np.ix_(ix,iy)]`?

Comment: My memory from past tests is the `np.take` is a little faster than the indexing notation.  But the advantage is small enough that wrapping it in a function call as you do could destroy it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487889/why-is-np-compress-faster-than-boolean-indexing

Comment: @Divakar: yes, I tried `np.ix_`  too (but omited it for shortness in my question): In my tests  `np.ix_`  was slower than the better np.take

Comment: Would `ix` and `iy` always follow such a pattern of constant stepsize within their indices?

Comment: @hpailj: you are right: I should try without the function-wrapping too. But I would like to write a rather complex CFD (computation fluid dynamics) code. So lean writing is essential, resp. un-lean code is very error prone.

Comment: `T[0:nx-2,1:ny-1]` is a view (basic indexing with 2 slices). `p(T,ix-1,iy)` is a copy, indexing with 2 arrays.  The sums will, of course, be a copy.  `take` could be faster than direct 'fancy' indexing, `T[ix-1,:][:,iy]`

Comment: @Divakar: I you might try `np.ix_` by introducing the following in my code above: ```from numpy import ix_ as q; 
ΔT_ix_  = T[q(ix-1,iy)] + T[q(ix+1,iy)] + T[q(ix,iy-1)] + T[q(ix,iy+1)] - 4.0 * T[q(ix,iy)]```

Comment: @hpaulj: direct fancy indexing does not work in 2 dimensions - I tryed. So `T[ix-1,iy]` does not give the desired result.

Comment: @Divakar: sorry, I misinterpreted your question: yes, in CFD (computational fluid dynamics) with structured grids the patterns of the indices `ix` and `iy` are usually not too wild. But there are large arrays.

Comment: Notice I used double indexing.  Alternatively `T[(ix-1)[:,None], iy]` or let `ix_` do that for you.

Comment: @pyano I guess in that case, you can use `slicing` : T[ix_start:ix_end:ix_stepsize,..]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexed version might be cleaned up with slice objects like this:

```
T[0:nx-2,1:ny-1] + T[2:nx,1:ny-1] + T[1:nx-1,0:ny-2]  + T[1:nx-1,2:ny] - 4.0 * T[1:nx-1,1:ny-1]

sy1 = slice(1,ny-1)
sx1 = slice(1,nx-1)
sy2 = slice(2,ny)
sy_2 = slice(0,ny-2)
T[0:nx-2,sy1] + T[2:nx,sy1] + T[sx1,xy_2]  + T[sx1,sy2] - 4.0 * T[sx1,sy1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Divakar and @hpaulj ! Yes, working with `slice` is viable too. Comparing all 4 approaches gives:

1. fastest ex aequo: t(`usual np`) and t(`slice`)
2. t(`take`) = 2 * t(`slice`)
3. t(`ix_`) = 3 * t(`slice`)

Here the code and the results:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ix_ as r
nx = 500;    ny = 500
T = np.arange(nx*ny).reshape(nx, ny)

ix = np.arange(1,nx-1); 
iy = np.arange(1,ny-1);

jx = slice(1,nx-1); jxm = slice(0,nx-2); jxp = slice(2,nx)
jy = slice(1,ny-1); jym = slice(0,ny-2); jyp = slice(2,ny)

#------------------------------------------------------------
def p(U,kx,ky):
    return np.take(np.take(U,kx, axis=0), ky,axis=1)
#------------------------------------------------------------

%timeit ΔT_slice= -T[jxm,jy]     + T[jxp,jy]     - T[jx,jym]     + T[jx,jyp]     - 0.0 * T[jx,jy]
%timeit ΔT_npy  = -T[0:nx-2,1:ny-1] + T[2:nx,1:ny-1] - T[1:nx-1,0:ny-2]  + T[1:nx-1,2:ny] - 0.0 * T[1:nx-1,1:ny-1]
%timeit ΔT_take = -p(T,ix-1,iy)  + p(T,ix+1,iy)  - p(T,ix,iy-1)  + p(T,ix,iy+1)  - 0.0 * p(T,ix,iy)
%timeit ΔT_ix_  = -T[r(ix-1,iy)] + T[r(ix+1,iy)] - T[r(ix,iy-1)] + T[r(ix,iy+1)] - 0.0 * T[r(ix,iy)]
.
100 loops, best of 3: 3.14 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.13 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.03 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.58 ms per loop
```

Concerning the discussion about view and copy the following might be instructive:

```
print("if False --> a view ;   if True --> a copy"  )
print("_slice_ :", T[jx,jy].base is None)
print("_npy_   :", T[1:nx-1,1:ny-1].base is None)
print("_take_  :", p(T,ix,iy).base is None)
print("_ix_    :", T[r(ix,iy)].base is None)
.
if False --> a view ;   if True --> a copy
_slice_ : False
_npy_   : False
_take_  : True
_ix_    : True
```